# Is the exhaust from an electric dryer harmful?

Tags: safety, dryer, appliances

We seem to have an exhaust leak from the dryer, as I can smell it when it's run.

**Is this an urgent issue?**

Since it's not gas, the exhaust should just be warm air, right? *(though in that case, why can I smell anything at all?)*

Comment: The problem is it is warm and very moist air.  The moisture can be a problem in a house.  Smell is okay if it is not burning/burnt smell.  Washing detergent/fabric softener like smell is okay.

Comment: This suggests you may have a clogged dryer vent. Google cleaning dryer vent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the exhaust from an electric dryer is not hazardous, at least if you're drying normal clothing and bedding.  So, you are correct, it's just warm moist air.

Some companies make heat savers that direct some of that air in the house. They save heat, but now the house is more prone to grow mold and the damp air being sucked into the drier takes longer to dry. So, don’t purchase one of those as they are really a scam, but its not harmful to breathe.

Comment: the humidity of the exhaust air can be mitigated by the dryer having a condensing feature. And they become a handy source of demineralized water for your steam iron while it's drying...

Comment: Ventless dryers, a.k.a condenser dryers, do just that: they exhaust ALL the air as dry air back into the laundry space. In Europe, this type of dryer is most common.

Comment: I understand ventless and agree the air would be dryer than the common us dryer. If us dryer coupled with a heat recovery ventilator that could save some monthly $ but there is the up front costs.

Answer (score 2):

The air itself, not harmful.

The rogue lint will certainly make the house dustier. If you have allergies/asthma then this could be an issue/harmful.

If the leak is inside your dryer and is gathering lint on the electrical components then it's a fire hazard. For this reason alone you should figure it out and fix it right away. This isn't one of those "back-burner" issues.